# Semaphore with queues

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, semaphore

Semaphore:

```
    public void enter() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (block) {
            ++current;
            if (current > permits) {
                try {
                    block.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw e;
                }

            }
        }

    }

    public void realese() {
        synchronized (block) {
            --current;
            block.notify();
        }

    }
```

How to make a queue in the semaphore? I want threads to be executed in the order of calling the enter().

Comment: "How do I do queues in this semaphore?" this is not sensible. Also: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: I don't know English well

Comment: You need to know English well enough to explain your problem and before you do that you need to try to solve it by yourself. @AnastasiosSelmanis Those comments don't make much sense if you don't downvote ;).

Comment: You also need to know how to use `wait()` and `notify()` before you go writing calls to them.  Read the [Guarded Blocks tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).  `wait()` and `notify()` are a low-level mechanism that is meant to be used in a very specific way.

Comment: This question is not at all "unclear."  The OP is asking how to implement a _fair_ semaphore---that is, a semaphore that guarantees that threads will be given "permits" in the same order that they requested them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

Have the `release()` method wake up every waiting thread (i.e., `block.notifyAll()`)

In the `enter()` method, have each waiting thread look at the head of the queue.

- If the thread at the head of the queue is the current thread, pop the queue and complete the `enter()` call,
   -OR-
- Go back to waiting otherwise.

But there's a subtle problem that I'll leave to you to work out how to fix:

- If thread A wakes up, finds itself at the head of the queue, pops the queue and returns,
- Then, thread B could wakes up, finds *its* self at the head of the queue, and *it also* pops the queue and returns.

And there you have one `release()` call which just allowed *two* threads to `enter()`.

That would be bad. So, you'll need to figure out a way to guarantee that no more than one thread can complete the `enter()` call each time `release()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

If your using a [newer java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) you can just add a fairness setting to the constructor.

```
Semaphore(int permits, boolean fair)
```

like this

```
private final Semaphore available = new Semaphore(MAX_AVAILABLE, true);
```